# Creating a tappable text section inside a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have the following problem, I have a textview that says something like this "By tapping the "I agree" button, I certify that I have read and agree to the Online Terms and Conditions"

what I want to do is to add a tap gesture recognizer to the part that says "Online Terms and Conditions" and call a method when the user taps this text section, if the user clicks in any other section of the text nothing should happen.

How can I do this? (I can't post any code due to the NDA I signed) :( I hope I can still be helped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a different UILabel and add it as a subview inside the UITextView, by doing this, you'll be able to add a gesture recognizer to the entire UILabel that calls the method you want. However, if you want it to show at the bottom if the UITextView, you need to use the UITextView delegate to show it when the scroll bar of the UITextView at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

You can use attributed string with the tag `NSLinkAttributeName` set for the range of tappable text. Then in the textView delegate implement

```
optional func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL:URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
```

Note that your text field must be selectable and non-editable for this to work.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview

Prior to iOS 10 you can use:

```
optional func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool`
```

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618606-textview

If you need to support both use the `@available` api - put `@available(iOS, deprecated: 10.0)` before pre-iOS 10 version and `@available(iOS 10.0, *)` before the one for iOS 10. That way you will avoid compile-time errors.

Comment: Thanks, and yes this would be the easiest solution but the deployment target is for iOS 9.0 which is not compatible with that method.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide you with a method suitable for the pre iOS 10 targets.

Comment: You can use both with the @available API to mark which function is valid for given target

Comment: I implemented your solution and I already got the range right, but for some reason when I tap on the text the delegate isn't being called.

Comment: Did you set `isSelectable` to `true` and `isEditable` to `false`?

Comment: Yes I did that, I put them in the override func awake from nib

    termsAndConditionsLabel.isSelectable = true
    termsAndConditionsLabel.isEditable = true 
    termsAndConditionsLabel.delegate = self